# Converting UTM55 to WGS84 in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

I've got a raster in UTM55 over Australia and I would like to convert it to WGS84. Any idea how to do it ?

The problem starts when ArcMap recognize it as 'Geo-Reference' only and not as UTM55, so I can't use the geographical transformation suggestion.

Is there a known command ?

Comment: When you add this raster to ArcMap what precisely is the message that you see?  By UTM55 I suspect that you mean MGA Zone 55 so can you be more precise about that too, please?  I suspect that you may need to georeference your raster but from your current description it is hard to be certain.  Also, the datum generally used in Australia is GDA94 rather than WGS84 so are you sure that it is WGS84 that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define the projection (data management toolbox > projection and transformation > define projection) and check that you are in the right coordinate system. Only after will you be able to change into another coordinate system. Both tools are in the data management toolbox. If you are are Australia, the full name will probably be UTM 55 S (datum WGS 84). In this case, you shouldn't need and datum transformation because you are already based on WGS 84. If you are using MGA 55 and not UTM 55 S, then your datum is GDA 1994 and you will need to specify the "GDA_1994_To_WGS_1984" transform in ArcGIS in order to correctly move to WGS 84.

If you know that your data comes from an UTM 55 S source but it doesn't display at the right location when you set the dataframe to UTM 55 S, then you could georeference your layer using the "georeferencing toolbar". If you are in the right coordinate system, you should only need to change the scale, translate and (maybe) rotate your image. If you need more, then you are not in the right coordinate system.